# only delete post within query / for each statement (front end)

Tags: wp-query, query, php

I am using this in my functions which I can use to delete the current page (custom post type called - bucket) and all it's children:

```
function delete_post(){
global $post;
$deletepostlink= add_query_arg( 'frontend', 'true',   get_delete_post_link( get_the_ID() ) );
if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) {
    echo '<span><a class="post-delete-link" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure to delete?\')" href="' . $deletepostlink . '">Delete  this </a></span>';
}
}

//Redirect after delete post in frontend
add_action('trashed_post','trash_redirection_frontend');
function trash_redirection_frontend($post_id) {
if ( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'frontend', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN ) ) {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order'=> 'ASC',
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'bucket'
    );
    // Filter through all pages and find Portfolio's children
    $children = get_children( $args );
    global $wpdb;
    foreach($children as $child){
        $childs[$child->ID] = $child->ID;
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} SET post_status = 'trash' WHERE ID IN   (" . implode( ', ', $childs ) . ")";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
wp_redirect();
    exit;
}
}
```

I then call this into my theme with this

```
<?php echo delete_post(); ?>
```

When I use this function within my page template displaying all my posts it obviously deletes the whole page and all it's children instead of just the individual post being called with a query / for each statement

Here is the example template code I am using and where my function is being called

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name Posts: Bucket Overview
*/
?>



<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


<div class="content">
<div class="stash-container">


<div class="main-view">

 <?php
 global $authordata, $post;
 $my_meta = get_post_meta( $id, 'connect', true);
 $portfolio_sections = array(
 'post_type'   => 'bucket',
 'category_name'      => 'Folder',
 'meta_key' => 'connect',
    'meta_value' => $my_meta,
 'orderby' => 'menu_order',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
 'sort_order'  => 'ASC'
  );

  $sections = get_posts($portfolio_sections);
  foreach ($sections as $section) { ?>


   <ul class="things">

     <div class="category"> <i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-   hidden="true"> </i> <?php echo $section->post_title; ?>
         (<?php $children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $section-  >ID, 'post_type'   => 'bucket',) ); echo count($children);?>)

  <span class="modify-folder">

  <?php echo delete_post(); ?> | edit

  </span>
  </div>


    <?php
    global $authordata, $post;
    $my_meta = get_post_meta( $id, 'connect', true);
    $portfolio_sites = array(
    'post_type'   => 'bucket',
    'category_name' => 'drop',
    'meta_key' => 'connect',
    'meta_value' => $my_meta,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'sort_order'  => 'ASC',
     'post_parent'      => $section->ID
     );

      $sites = get_posts($portfolio_sites);


      foreach ($sites as $site) { ?>
      <li class="sites">

       <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($site->ID); ?>">

      <div class="rollover"> 

    </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?> 
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So you can see within the above template in the span class - modify-folder I am calling my delete link. But it is deleting the whole page not just the $section->ID - I have tried changing all references to get_the_id and post_id in the main function file to be $section->ID instead but it doesnt work!

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Try changing `$childs[$child->ID] = $child->ID;` to `$childs[] = $child->ID;` - key indexed arrays are squiffy with implosion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in the id of the post you want to delete as an argument of the delete_post() function rather than relying on obtaining it via global $post within the function itself:

```
<?php echo delete_post($section->ID); ?>
```

Then in your delete_post() function you can use the passed-in argument like so:

```
function delete_post($sectionid){
    $deletepostlink= add_query_arg( 'frontend', 'true',   get_delete_post_link( $sectionid ) );
    if (current_user_can('edit_post', $sectionid)) {
        echo '<span><a class="post-delete-link" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure to delete?\')" href="' . $deletepostlink . '">Delete  this </a></span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! Will try this out when I get home - so to clarify it's only - $sectionid for the passed in argument in the actual function and not $section->id?

Comment: That is correct. You could name it whatever you want once you're within the function, I just kept it close to the original so as to be descriptive. It would also make sense for it to be $postid or even just $id. But when you pass it in it has to be $section->ID

Comment: Great! So assume to ensure children get deleted too I set post parent in my after trash function to be $sectionid also? Thanks for your time - I'll make to mark as right in an hour or so when I give it a go!

Comment: just tried this out and it's not working! It's close it seems now delete the correct post along with its parent - instead of it's children which it should do!

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're wanting to do then. I thought you wanted it to delete the section and it was not deleting the specific one?

Comment: I was being silly - missed a $! Thanks for your help your answer was correct.